# Why are Cartan subalgebras preserved under epimorphism?

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $f:L\to L'$ be an epimorphism of finite dimension Lie algebras. Let $H$ be a Cartan subalgebra in $L$. Prove that $f(H)$ is a Cartan subalgebra in $L'$.

Comment: Bourbaki, Lie, Chap. VII, §2, 1., Corollary 2 of Proposition 4. The ground field is just supposed to be infinite. (Obviously the only issue to to show that $f(H)$ equals its own normalizer in $L'$.)

Comment: Still it's a good question, although the exercise-way of putting it makes it tempting to close it. It's not a standard exercise and my short answer hides many basic facts on representations of nilpotent Lie algebras that are **not** covered by most textbooks.

Comment: Hi liorz, As YCor suggests, MO doesn't tend to like questions phrased as homework exercises. If you rewrite this more ... colloquially? ... it will read better. Be sure to take a look at how other questions are worded, and read about the scope etc of MO.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a proof valid over arbitrary fields in the book "Abstract Lie algebras" by David Winter (Section 4.4.5, Theorem 4.4.5.1).

Answer (score 2):

Let me give a proof working at least in characteristic zero.

Recall that $\mathfrak{h}$ is Cartan means that $\mathfrak{h}$ is nilpotent, equal to its own normalizer.

It also means (at least in characteristic zero) that, denoting $\mathfrak{h}^\infty(\mathfrak{g})$ for $\mathrm{ad}(\mathfrak{h})^n(\mathfrak{g})=[\mathfrak{h},[\mathfrak{h},[\dots,[\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{g}]\cdots]]]$ for large $n$ (say $n\ge\dim\mathfrak{g}$), that $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h}\oplus \mathfrak{h}^\infty(\mathfrak{g})$. Or equivalently that $\mathfrak{h}$ is nilpotent and $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h}+\mathfrak{h}^\infty(\mathfrak{g})$. This latter condition clearly passes to quotients.

Comment: How you define ad(H)? Do you mean ad(H)= [H,L]?

Comment: Why L=h⊕h∞(g) ? And why this finish the quetion?

Comment: This finishes the question because as I said, this condition passes to quotients. Why $L=H\oplus H^\infty(G)$ (and why conversely $L=H\oplus H^\infty(G)$ implies conversely $H$ Cartan)... follows from weight decomposition of a finite-dimensional vector space under the action of a nilpotent Lie algebra. This is the very beginning of Bourbaki, Lie Chap VII (and basically this is why Cartan subalgebras are useful). Actually they work without characteristic assumption (maybe the field should be infinite still).